# Conceptual reusable orbital launch engine prototype for nanosatellites

Tags: launch, low-earth-orbit, design-alternative, spaceplane

I have realised that the process in which we go to space is highly inefficient and we should create a hypersonic spaceplane which take offs and goes to low earth orbit to release nanosatelite and lands back like a normal plane. I have made it compulsory to include a scramjet and a rocket engine to make it challenging. I was wondering if you guys could give me tips and ideas towards my conceptual design, and things to consider when carrying it out.

Comment: Hi Jot, welcome. Please have a look at all the other posts here on alternate orbital solutions - you will see there is a lot more to it than can be answered in one post :-)